# Firebase trigger functions works alternately

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I wrote this firebase function that triggers when data is added, it summarizes the child values and updates the total value field.

```
    export const updateTotalAnswersCounts = functions.database
    .ref('/CurrentGame/answers/{aid}').onWrite((change, context) => {
    var collectionRef = change.after.ref.parent;
    let total = 0;
     collectionRef.once('value',(snapshot)=>{
        console.log('snapshot',snapshot.val())
        snapshot.forEach((childSnapshot)=>{
            if(childSnapshot.val()!=null){
                console.log('childSnapshot',childSnapshot.val())
                total+=Number(childSnapshot.val())
            }
            return false;
        })
        const updates = {}
        updates['/totalAnswersCount'] = total;
        firebase.ref('/CurrentGame').update(updates)

    })

    return true;


});
```

the function trigger works when I add new value to 'answers' node then it takes all the numbers (in this photo 1+2+11) then it update the totalAnswersCount to the sum = 14.

this add operation

```
addAnswer() {
    let answer = 3;
    let userInfo = {
        uid: this.uid, 
        gid: '1',
        qid: '2',
        aid: '3'
    }
    const answer_ref = firebase.database().ref(`CurrentGame/answers/${answer}`);
    const users_answers_ref = firebase.database().ref(`GameQuestionStats/${this.user.uid}/${userInfo.qid}`);

    // Return the promise from countRef.transaction() so our function
    // waits for this async event to complete before it exits.
    return answer_ref.transaction((current) => {
        return (current || 0) + 1;
    }).then(() => {
        return users_answers_ref.set(userInfo,{merge:true})
    });
}
```

[image]

this firebase function works alternately

1. when I first load the app, it node update and not make any update.
2. sometimes it has delay and updates after 3-4 sec.
3. sometimes it updates in real time and works fine.

Comment: What exactly is your question/problem?

Comment: why is this happend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that you have to chain the Promises (and therefore return a promise at each chaining step).

The following should work:

```
export const updateTotalAnswersCounts = functions.database
.ref('/CurrentGame/answers/{aid}').onWrite((change, context) => {
    const collectionRef = change.after.ref.parent;
    let total = 0;

    return collectionRef.once('value', (snapshot) => {

        console.log('snapshot', snapshot.val())

        snapshot.forEach((childSnapshot) => {
            if (childSnapshot.val() != null) {
                console.log('childSnapshot', childSnapshot.val())
                total += Number(childSnapshot.val())
            }
        })

    }).then(() => {
        const updates = {}
        updates['/totalAnswersCount'] = total
        return firebase.ref('/CurrentGame').update(updates)
    }).catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
        //Error treatment
    });

});
```

I would suggest that you look at Doug Stevenson's videos on the subject:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7IkUgCLr5oA&t=515s

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=652XeeKNHSk

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d9GrysWH1Lc&t=4s

Note that case nbr 2 (it has delay and updates after 3-4 sec.) is a classic behavior when you don't return a promise in a Cloud Function.

Comment: it works fine now! I don't really understand why I need to return promise in cloud functions but I will look on the videos

Comment: each operation in firebase, update,set,delete,once, should I need to return promise? is this function https://pastebin.com/L1DEHNJL should work okay? or do I need change it?

Comment: @AdirZoari I "personally" think it should work correctly, because it is MY answer to your question of yesterday!!! :-))) And yes, by default all this database method returns a promise. Look at the videos, it really worth spending the time doing so.

Comment: Hey renaud, I checked some times, it has problem again. when I open the app first time, then increament the answer, it should summarize and set the update total but it has delay. it happen after we don't use the increament method for some minutes.. it looks like it 'freeze' or 'cold time'

Comment: @AdirZoari I think this is due to the time the machine where the Cloud Function is executed needs to start. This is inherent to a serveless platform. You will see that after the first time it is really fast.

Comment: yes, after first time, it really fast and it real time. But the first time is also important to me.. there is any way to solve it?

Comment: @AdirZoari I don't think so: as I said this is a characteristic of a serverless platform. The server(s) hosting your Firebase project are not running all the time but only when they get queries.

Comment: Hey, Function execution took 4248 ms and even more.. what can I do?

Comment: @AdirZoari You may ask a new Stack Overflow question explaining that your Cloud Function takes a long time to run the first time after it has been inactive for a while and that you would like to know if there is a solution. Firebase experts, Doug or Frank, may answer.

Comment: Okay but its not just in first time. Yesterday it works good. Now it bit slow

Answer (score 0):

One change I would recommend is to make use of the value from **change** and append the sum to your total answers count.

eg: `total = total+(newvalue-oldvalue);`

this will save you the trouble from loading all the values from 'once' operation, which will be very costly if your data grows.

Finally, the reason (which I suspect) for your alternative working might be because of **promises**, which are getting executed from your 'once' operation. Hope this helps you.

Comment: not sure what you mean. can you please edit my function and let me know what you mean?